# Download folder/dock stack settings

Tags: macos, dock

Where do if find the download dock folder stack settings so I can change them to see fan or somehow get the most recent download to show up first?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on any folder in your dock to change the way files are sorted, how the stack displays in the dock, and how files are displayed.

[image: Right click options]